# How can I insert a line of text/code on keypress in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext

I want to be able to insert import ipdb; pdb.set_trace() on the line below where I am on a key press.
For obvious reasons ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two fairly easy ways to do this:

Create a snippet... go to Tools>Developer>New snippet, bung this in:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[import ipdb; pdb.set_trace()]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>p</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

save it.. should start working straight away.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (puts you onto a new next line),
- <kbd>p</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (inserts your snippet).

4 key strokes.

OR

You could use the macro tool:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (start recording macro)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (puts you onto a new next line)
- type: import ipdb; pdb.set_trace()
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (end recording macro)

Now save your_macro.sublime-macro (Tools>Save macro), and add this key binding to your user key bindings:

```
{ "keys": ["p"], "command": "run_macro_file", 
"args": {"file": "Packages/User/your_macro.sublime-macro"} }
```

now 'p' will insert your text, on the next line..

1 key stroke... but you must be careful to write code that never needs the letter p... ;)

Comment: Thank you! The ctr+alt+q doesn't work in OS X. But From the menu I got it to work. And of course changed the key to something else, ctr+p in this case.

Comment: Wow, this has to be the clunkiest way to set up key binds in an editor ever. Well, even setting settings is clunky. Too lazy to make a settings editor, I think.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS X I have to save it with extension:

`.sublime-snippet`

to get it working.